# Register multiple styles / scripts in register_block_type

Tags: block-editor

I use following code to register my Gutenberg Block:

```php
register_block_type('create-block/myblock', array(
    'editor_script' => 'create-block-myblock-script-editor',
    'script' => 'create-block-myblock-script',
    'editor_style' => 'create-block-myblock-style-editor',
    'style' => 'create-block-myblock-style-1',
));
// register scripts & styles
wp_register_script('create-block-myblock-script-editor', $urlScriptEditor, array());
wp_register_script('create-block-myblock-script', $urlScript, array());
wp_register_style('create-block-myblock-style-editor', $urlEditor, array());
wp_register_style('create-block-myblock-style-1', $urlOne, array());
```

Now I want to register a second stylesheet for the front-end:

```php
wp_register_style('create-block-myblock-style-2', $urlTwo, array());
```

How can I hook into the block register as only one script is  intended for each case?

Answer (score 0):

Not supported yet, see the [corresponding Github Issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/14598).
I found a workaround in order to at least register additional block styles:

```
register_block_style(
    'create-block/myblock', array(
        'name'         => 'style2',
        'label'        => 'Style 2',
        'style_handle' => 'create-block-myblock-style-2',
    )
);
```